# How to get event.target as an object in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

First, I'm sorry to my deficient english.

.

I want write code if click anywhere except `.do-not-click-here`, call `myFunction()`.

So I wrote code like below.

```
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if(event.target.classList.includes('do-not-click-here')) {
    myFunction();
  }
)
```

But this code return error "Property 'classList' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'."

.

So I tried debugging through `console.log`.

.

When I tried `console.log(event);`

[image]

received `event.target` as a javascript object. (I want it)

.

When I tried `console.log(event.target);`

[image]

received `event.target` as an element(?). so `event.target.classList` is not working. (Maybe)

.

How to get `event.target.classList`?

or is there a better way than I thought for I wanted?

Comment: Can you try `(event.target as HTMLElement).classList...`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer could you please add as an answer?

Answer (score 13):

Other answers are good, this is just a more-angular-style alternative. You can create a global click listener in any of your components this way:

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
onClick(element: HTMLElement) {
    if(element.classList.contains('do-not-click-here')) {
        myFunction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button (click)="onClick($event)">click</button>

export class Component{


onClick(event){
   if(event.target.classList.contains('do-not-click-here')) {
    myFunction();
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if(event.target.classList.contains('do-not-click-here')) {
    myFunction();
  }
)
```

use `contains` instead `includes`

Answer (score 0):

you can be REALLY angular use a class as a directive selector:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '.do-not-click-here'
})
export class DoNotClickDirective {
  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log('dont click me!', event);
  }
}
```

now everything with that class will run that function when clicked

blitz (check / click hello component for usage): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-zfzrrb?file=src/app/do-not-click.directive.ts